# Smallest connected domain extent outside of which f[x] = 0

Tags: functiondomain

Consider a function such as:

```
f[x_] := HeavisideLambda[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x]
```

[image]

I'm seeking a function, analogous to `FunctionDomain[]`, that gives the single smallest range of values of x outside of which the function is 0.  For the specific function defined above, I'd like the output to be

```
myDomain[f[x]]
```

$-7 < x < 17$

The naive approach of solving for f[x] = 0 will not work, of course, because that condition might be satisfied *within* the range I seek.

I've tried some logical operations using `Reduce`, `Resolve`, and `ForAll`, but always seem to find a counterexample function where it doesn't work.

(It would be nice if myDomain[] gave results for functions that may not go to zero at $+\infty$ or not go to zero at $-\infty$ as well, yielding answers such as $x<10$.)

I of course want myDomain[] to work with *symbolic* expressions, not just numerical ones, and yield the smallest region consistent with the constraints.

Test cases:

- `(HeavisideLambda[x] - HeavisidePi[x - 2]) Sin[x]` should give $-1 \leq x < 5/2$
- `(UnitBox[x - 1/2] + UnitBox[x + 2]) Exp[-x]` should give $-5/2 \leq x < 1$
- `Piecewise[{{1, -1 < x < 2}, {-1, 3 < x < 4}}]` should give $-1 \leq x < 4$
- `If[25 x^2 - 2 x^4 - 50 > 0, 1, 0] Sin[x]` should give $\sqrt{10} \leq x \leq \sqrt{10}$

Background:  I need this operation so I can then "periodize" candidate functions... repeat each infinitely to the left and right on the number line to make a function defined everywhere and expressible in a Fourier series.  For that reason I need a *single* region.

for some functions, such as f[x_]:= 1, or Sin[x], or Exp[-Abs[x]], or Exp[-x^2], and infinitely many others, the answer should be "None", because there is no threshold value above which the function is always 0, or another threshold value below which the function is always 0.

---

A much harder "bonus" question (not needed for solution acceptance) would be to generalize this problem to two dimensions, i.e., "shrink wrap" a region around a two dimensional region outside of which a function f[x,y] is zero.

Comment: @David.G.Stork `Collect[f[x] // FunctionExpand,  HeavysideTheta[p_], Simplify ]
(*1/12 ((-17 + x) HeavisideTheta[-17 + x] - 
   2 (-5 + x) HeavisideTheta[-5 + x] + (7 + x) HeavisideTheta[
     7 + x]) Sin[x]*)`   perhaps takes you one step further

Comment: In general, `Integrate` $f(x)^2$ from $x=-\infty$ to $x=u$. Since the square is positive, the point where the function starts rising on the left from zero gets your leftmost point. Likewise, all you have to do is flip it over and integrate $f(-x)^2$ to determine the right side of the interval. However, the integral is not always easy, like in this case.

Comment: Your requirement of a single region has no sense for some functions. What would be your region for function `If[25 x^2 - 2 x^4 - 50 < 0, 1, 0]`? Notice `<` instead of `>` in your original function.

Comment: For the function you quote, the answer would be "None" because there is no region for which the value is zero above some threshold.  Likewise for f[x] = 1.  or sin(x), or Exp[Abs[x]] or...   If you change the sign, then there is a well-defined connected region for which the function is zero above some threshold, and below some (other) threshold.  Clear?

Comment: Because `FunctionExpand[HeavisideLambda[x]]` results in `-HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] - 
 2 x HeavisideTheta[x] + HeavisideTheta[1 + x] + 
 x HeavisideTheta[1 + x]`, `HeavisideLambda` is a distribution, not a usual function and the question about its zero values makes no sense (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) for info).

Comment: @user64494 You can replace `HeavisideLambda` with `Piecewise[{{1 + x, -1 < x < 0}, {1, x == 0}, {1 - x, 0 < x < 1}}, 0]` or equivalently `PDF[TriangularDistribution[{-1, 1}], x]` which is a proper piecewise function.

Comment: You can get a partial result for some functions using `FunctionDomain` on the reciprocal. `f[x_] := UnitTriangle[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x]
Reduce[FunctionDomain[1/f[x], x], x]`. This would need extra processing though to remove parts that are not on the rays to the infinities. And I don't think it will play nice with the distribution cousins to these functions, such as `Heavisidelambda`.

Comment: @flinty:No, it is not possible. As written in my comment, "Because `FunctionExpand[HeavisideLambda[x]]` results in -`HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] -   2 x HeavisideTheta[x] + HeavisideTheta[1 + x] +   x HeavisideTheta[1 + x]`, `HeavisideLambda` is a distribution" . I add that this distribution is not generated by any usual function (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Further_reading)), but `Piecewise[{{1 + x, -1 < x < 0}, {1, x == 0}, {1 - x, 0 < x < 1}}, 0]` is a usual function.

Comment: @user64494 I get that, but you're being pedantic and detracting from the general question. `HeavisideLambda` takes a number, returns a number. Here we're only concerned with Mathematica's implementation of it, which very obviously was used here as a shorthand for the piecewise function. The purpose is to get a graph that has those flat parts on the left and right. Yes, it's bad Mathematics, but no it's not a big issue with this question. If you're worried by things like this, why not insist on Static Single Assignment any time somebody writes something non-Mathematical like `a = a + 1`?

Comment: Hey @flinty...since you mention `a=a+1` I'm giving you homework. Evaluate that expression three times in a fresh kernel. Explain the behavior you encounter. (This requires version 13.2 or higher.) If nothing else, it will be a distraction from what you refer to as pedantry.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I was assuming `a` was given a value already to make the point Programming != Mathematics, but you got me there: `3 + TerminatedEvaluation["RecursionLimit"]` and it gives up producing messages on the third one and after :)

Comment: @flinty It took me a couple of hours in a debugging WL kernel to understand first, why the message stops and second, why it does not stop after the first time. Mind you, I’m fairly familiar with the workings of TerminatedEvaluation. What a chase through (my own) code it was though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] := HeavisideLambda[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x]
FunctionExpand@f[x] /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep // PiecewiseExpand
Or @@ %[[1, All, 2]] // FullSimplify
```

---

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{12} (17 \sin (x)-x \sin (x)) & 5\leq x<17 \\
 \frac{1}{12} (x \sin (x)+7 \sin (x)) & -7\leq x<5 \\
 0 & \text {True}
\end{cases}$$

```
-7 <= x < 17
```

**Update after OP changed the question:**

```
fu[exp_] := 
 With[{bb = 
    FunctionExpand@exp /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep // 
     PiecewiseExpand}, 
  If[Head[bb] === Piecewise, 
   With[{b = 
      Or @@ Replace[
         bb[[1, All, 2]], {x < q_ | x <= q_ :> -∞ < x < q, 
          x > q_ | x >= q_ :> ∞ > x > q}, ∞] // 
       LogicalExpand}, 
    Min@Join[
       Join[Cases[{b}, x > _, ∞], 
         Cases[{b}, x >= _, ∞]][[All, 2]], 
       Join[Cases[{b}, _ < x, ∞], 
         Cases[{b}, _ <= x, ∞]][[All, 1]]] < x < 
     Max@Join[
       Join[Cases[{b}, x < _, ∞], 
         Cases[{b}, x <= _, ∞]][[All, 2]], 
       Join[Cases[{b}, _ > x, ∞], 
         Cases[{b}, _ >= x, ∞]][[All, 1]]]], -∞ < 
    x < ∞]]
```

---

---

```
fu[HeavisideLambda[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x]]
fu[(HeavisideLambda[x] - HeavisidePi[x - 2]) Sin[x]]
fu[(UnitBox[x - 1/2] + UnitBox[x + 2]) Exp[-x]]
fu[Piecewise[{{1, -1 < x < 2}, {-1, 3 < x < 4}}]]
fu[If[25 x^2 - 2 x^4 - 50 > 0, 1, 0] Sin[x]]

fu[If[25 x^2 - 2 x^4 - 50 < 0, 1, 0] Sin[x]]
fu[Sin[x]]
fu[Sin[x] (UnitStep[x] + UnitStep[x - 1])]
fu[Sin[x] (UnitStep[x] - UnitStep[x - 1])]
```

---

```
-7 < x < 17

-1 < x < 5/2

-(5/2) < x < 1

-1 < x < 4

-Sqrt[10] < x < Sqrt[10]


-∞ < x < ∞

-∞ < x < ∞

0 < x < ∞

0 < x < 1
```

Comment: @David G. Stork: Works well for me with the output $-1\leq x<1\lor \frac{3}{2}\leq x<\frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: No no no.  You don't understand.  It has to be the *single* connected region outside of which the function f[x] is zero... here $-1 \leq x < 5/2$.  The function may or may not be zero at points within that single region (domain), as in this case.

Comment: @David G. Stork: It is not me not understanding but you imprecisely stating what you want. (You edited your question only now) Furthermore what prevents you from computing $-1 \leq x < 5/2$ from $-1\leq x<1\lor \frac{3}{2}\leq x<\frac{5}{2}$? It is not that hard. It is ordinary comparison of bounds of intervals and taking the desired ones.

Comment: In a few minutes, see the edited (clarified) question.  At the very least, you simply cannot "hand tune" the solution to the fact that there is a `HeavisidePi`, as you do.  Note the new test cases.  (I'll add more.)

Comment: Because `FunctionExpand[HeavisideLambda[x]]` results in `-HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] + x HeavisideTheta[-1 + x] - 
 2 x HeavisideTheta[x] + HeavisideTheta[1 + x] + 
 x HeavisideTheta[1 + x]`, `HeavisideLambda` is a distribution, not a usual function and the question about its zero values makes no sense (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) for info). You replaced a distribution `HeavisideTheta` by a usual function `UnitStep`. This is another question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: `FunctionExpand[HeavisidePi[x]]` results in `-HeavisideTheta[-(1/2) + x] + HeavisideTheta[1/2 + x]`. This means that `HeavisidePi` is a distribution, not a usual function `UnitStep`.

Comment: Yep... there we go.  Thanks.  ($\checkmark$)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and then [`RegionBounds`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html) (or [`BoundingRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html)) to get the upper and lower bound of the calculated region.

It works for 3 of your 5 test cases.

```
findFunctionSupportBounds[f_, x_] := First@RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[f != 0, x]]

f1 = HeavisideLambda[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x];
f2 = (HeavisideLambda[x] - HeavisidePi[x - 2]) Sin[x];
f3 = (UnitBox[x - 1/2] + UnitBox[x + 2]) Exp[-x] ;
f4 = Piecewise[{{1, -1 < x < 2}, {-1, 3 < x < 4}}];
f5 = If[25 x^2 - 2 x^4 - 50 > 0, 1, 0] Sin[x];

findFunctionSupportBounds[#, x] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}
(*
  unevaluated,
  unevaluated,
  {-(5/2), 1},
  {-1, 4},
  {-Sqrt[10], Sqrt[10]}
*)
```

We can handle the first two cases numerically.

```
eps = 10^-10;
maxBound = {-1000, 1000};
findFunctionSupportBoundsNumerically[f_, x_] := 
 Chop@First@RegionBounds[DiscretizeRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[f > eps || f < -eps, x], maxBound]]

findFunctionSupportBoundsNumerically[#, x] & /@ {f1, f2}
(*
 {-7., 17.}
 {-1., 2.5}
*)
```

However, we can also do a simple trick of preprocessing the distributions (`Heaviside*`) into regular functions which Mathematica will then handle smoothly.

```
preprocessDistributions[f_, x_] := f /. 
 {HeavisideLambda -> UnitTriangle, HeavisidePi -> UnitBox, HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep};

findFunctionSupportBounds[f_, x_] := 
 First@RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[preprocessDistributions[f, x] != 0, x]]

findFunctionSupportBounds[#, x] & /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}
(*
 {-7, 17}
 {-1, 5/2}
 {-(5/2), 1}
 {-1, 4}
 {-Sqrt[10], Sqrt[10]}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks... a big help ($+1$).  But I need this to work with *symbolic* cases as well, where your numerical method cannot.  (I'll add a few such test cases.)

Comment: You wrote "We can handle the first two cases numerically". However, both `HeavisideLambda[(x - 5)/12] Sin[x]` and `(HeavisideLambda[x] - HeavisidePi[x - 2]) Sin[x]` are distributions and this explains "unevaluated"s since `f != 0` makes no sense. Numerical calculations may fail with distributions as an example `NIntegrate[DiracDelta[x], {x, -2, 1}]` demonstrates.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, please see my update with preprocessing of distributions. Note that my approach with `RegionBounds` can be simply upgraded to multi-dimensional cases because they are naturally supported within `Region` framework.

Comment: @Domen Nice answer. One little correction: rule in `preprocessDistributions[f_, x_] := ...` should be `HeavisideLambda[y_] :> UnitTriangle[y ]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I was thinking of that, but does it really matter? Since we are only looking for the boundaries of the support ... Well, perhaps one can construct a function where it matters – thanks, I've changed it (and it looks better anyways) :)